# PHP Excel image link

Tags: php, image, excel, hyperlink

I am using [PHP Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library and have a problem.

I need to insert into a cell image as hyperlink. Is it possible, any suggesions?

Tryed to dran an image

```
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);

        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();        
        $objDrawing->setImageResource($image);        

        $columnLetter = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex - 1);

        $this->imageColumns[$columnLetter] = 1;

        $coordinate = $columnLetter . $rowIndex;

        $objDrawing->setCoordinates($coordinate);
        $objDrawing->setResizeProportional(false);
        $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
        $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);        
        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You can't set an image as a hyperlink, but you can set the cell that it's overlaid on as a hyperlink

Comment: i found an example `->getCell()->getHyperlink()->setUrl('url');`